# how to add aliases to vagrant vm .bashrc file

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I'm trying to provision a vm with some alias and keep getting permision denied, wondering what the proper way of doing this is:

end of Vagrant file (this works): `config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision.sh"`

in provision.sh: `echo "alias alias1=\"some command\"" >> .bashrc`

error: `/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 6: .bashrc: Read-only file system`

Comment: Have you tried it like this?
`echo "alias alias1=\"some command\"" >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: this ended up being a coreOS issue (I think it has to do with it's read only file system or something like that, I should have mentioned it in the question), I ended up using Ubuntu for my VM (I'm only using the VM to run Docker) and the above command in your comment/my original question ended up working.

Answer (score 2):

this ended up being a coreOS issue (I think it has to do with it's read only file system or something like that, I should have mentioned it in the question), I ended up using Ubuntu for my VM (I'm only using the VM to run Docker) and the above command in your comment/my original question ended up working.

Answer (score 1):

CoreOS has some specific issue about that as by default `~/.bashrc` is symlinked into `/usr` (read-only folder).

You can replace the symlink with a copy of the file and then make edits. Something like this in your `provision.sh` would do the trick:

```
cp $(readlink .bashrc) .bashrc.new && mv .bashrc.new .bashrc
echo "alias alias1=\"some command\"" >> .bashrc
```

I cannot test as I do not have CoreOS box but it should work

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Ansible Playbooks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks.html), you can create a new task role in yml file, in example:

```
- name: Update bashrc to add foo alias for Vagrant user
  lineinfile:
    dest=/home/vagrant/.bashrc
    line="alias foo='bar'"
    regexp="^alias foo"
    owner=vagrant
    state=present
    insertafter=EOF
    create=True
```

then run the ansible script (`sudo ansible-playbook foo.yml`) from your vagrant provision file.

Alternatively use `ex` to append alias to the end of the file:

```
ex -s +':$s@$@\ralias foo=bar@' -cwq /etc/bash.bashrc
```

See also: [How to append some line at the end of the file only if it's not there yet?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4847/467) in Ex